# Disable Drop & Drop In WPF GridView Column Headers

Tags: wpf, xaml, drag-and-drop

Does anyone know how to do this? I am really surprised at the scarce documentation/sample code for the WPF GridView (ListView View=GridView).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to set AllowsColumnReorder="False" on a GridView

sample code:

```
<ListView.View>
    <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False"> 

        //your stuff...

    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Kamil, the solution works fine... 

BTW, I found it myself also :) but it took me 4 hours.
Maybe waiting your answer is a good idea.
thanks a lot!